# How to configure Redis to persist data after reboot on Linux?

Tags: redis, redis-server, redisclient

I installed Redis on Ubuntu 16.04. I couldn't find Redis directory nor redis.conf file (tried with: `sudo find redis.conf`).

My application depends on some data pulled from third party APIs. I store the (processed) data in Redis. My problem is, after reboot I lose the data. I guess I need to specify in config file that the data should be persisted on reboot, but I couldn't find the config file. Do I need to create the config file? Are there some templates to use? My goal is just to have the data persisted after reboot.

Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

Use `dpkg -L redis-server | grep redis.conf` to find config file path. It should be located at `/etc/redis/redis.conf` as I know.

Redis has 2 methods for persistense: `Snapshotting` and `Append-only file`:

- `Snapshotting` will be enabled by adding (or uncommenting) `save X Y` in config file. It means Redis will automatically dump the dataset to disk every `X` seconds if at least `Y` keys changed. There could be more than one `save` options in config file.
- `Append-only file` will be enabled by adding (or uncommenting) `appendonly yes` in config file

Comment: I didn't do any of these changes but my keys were still there even after a redis-server restart, why?? @seyed

Comment: @AATHITHRAJENDRAN Three 'save' commands are enabled by default in 'redis.conf', so it's normal behavior.

Comment: thanks, by default they already have 3 `save` command for us, so the point of `snapshotting` could be pass (or you can modify as you want), now just need to enable `appendonly yes` will make redis to be persistent.

Answer (score 5):

you should turn on the rdb or aof.

see https://redis.io/topics/persistence

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the config file.

appendonly yes

This will append data as you store new data. This enables durability.

Comment: Do I need to create the config file? I couldn't find in my file system a file named redis.conf.

Comment: config file is present by default. just edit it. path of config file : redis-server /etc/redis.conf

Comment: This will enable aof persistence which may or may not be the mode you want.  Depending on your durability and performance needs you may want to use RDB persistence.